# overloading operator * c++

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading

I have been trying to compile this program but it is giving me an error in regards to overloading the * operator for one of the functions: **complex operator *(double n)const**

When I try to compile I get the error: **no match for 'operator*' in '2 * c'**

Here is the header file:

**Complex.h**

```
#ifndef COMPLEX0_H
#define COMPLEX0_H

class complex {
    double realNum;
    double imagNum;
public:
    complex();
    complex(double x,double y);
    complex operator *(double n)const;
    complex operator *(const complex &c1)const;
   friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is,complex &cm);
   friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os,const complex &cm);
};

#endif
```

Here is the cpp:

**Complex.cpp**

```
 #include "iostream"
#include "complex0.h"

complex::complex() {
    imagNum = 0.0;
    realNum = 0.0;
}

complex::complex(double x, double y) {

    realNum = x;
    imagNum = y;
}

complex complex::operator *(const complex& c1) const{
complex sum;
sum.realNum=realNum*c1.realNum-c1.imagNum*imagNum;
sum.imagNum=realNum*c1.imagNum+imagNum*c1.realNum;
    return sum;
}

complex complex::operator *(double n)const{ 
    complex sum;
    sum.realNum=realNum*n;
    sum.imagNum=imagNum*n;
    return sum;

}
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream& is, complex& cm) {
    is >> cm.realNum>> cm.imagNum;
    return is;
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream& os, const complex& cm){
os<<"("<<cm.realNum<<","<<cm.imagNum<<"i)"<<"\n";    
return os;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "complex0.h" 

    int main() {
        complex a(3.0, 4.0); 
        complex c;
        cout << "Enter a complex number (q to quit):\n";
        while (cin >> c) {
            cout << "c is " << c << "\n";
            cout << "a is " << a << "\n";
            cout << "a * c" << a * c << "\n";
            cout << "2 * c" << 2 * c << "\n";
            cout << "Enter a complex number (q to quit):\n";
        }
        cout << "Done!\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Can someone explain to me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Because you only take `complex` on the left side, never a double.

Comment: The error I am getting is: no match for 'operator*' in '2 * c'

Comment: @chris what do you mean.

Comment: Every non-static function in your class has a first parameter of your class type.

Comment: Binary operators which do not assign should not be member functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member function operator only applies when the *first* operand is of your class type. If you want to handle the case where the *second* operand is of your type, you need also a free function (in which we simply delegate to the member function by virtue of commutativity of the operation):

```
complex operator*(double n, complex const & x)
{
    return x * n;
}
```

(Please note that the standard library already contains `<complex>`.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a member function defined as follows:

```
complex complex::operator *(double n) const;
```

That will let you do things like: `complex_number * 3.0`, but not `3.0 * complex_number`. However, you can't create a member function that will let you do `3.0 * complex_number`. The only place you could create that member function, is inside the definition of `double`, which you can't change.

Instead of doing it as member functions though, you can also do it as free-standing functions:

```
complex operator*(complex x, double n); // Called for complex_number * 2.0
complex operator*(double n, complex x); // Called for 2.0 * complex_number
```